# Cell Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Short question regarding excel formatting.

I am currently working on a userform-based protocol tool. The userform basically consists of two input windows, one which loads the exisitng bullet points and one to add new points.

Additionally, I would like to have the date in bold font added to each bullet point. I implemented that by searching for the position in the string where the date occurs (via `instrrev`) and then changing the font for the next 10 characters to bold font.

Now it works perfectly fine when creating a new bullet point, but it always messes up when I add an additional point to an existing topic or when I  change an old bullet point (Then the whole text is bold). Anyone knows why this happens?

```
Private Sub Fertig_Click()
    Dim neu As String
    Dim i As Integer
    neu = Date & ": " & mitschrieb_neu.Value


    'No Changes
    If mitschrieb_neu.Value = "" And mitschrieb_alt.Value = ActiveCell.Value Then
        Unload Me
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'First bullet point
    If mitschrieb_neu.Value <> "" And ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = neu
        i = InStrRev(ActiveCell.Value, Date)
        ActiveCell.Characters(i, 10).Font.Bold = True
        Unload Me
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'New bullet point
    If mitschrieb_neu.Value <> "" And ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & Chr(10) & neu
        i = InStrRev(ActiveCell.Value, Date)
        ActiveCell.Characters(i, 10).Font.Bold = True
        Unload Me
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Changed an old bullet point
    If mitschrieb_neu.Value = "" And mitschrieb_alt.Value <> ActiveCell.Value Then
        ActiveCell.Value = mitschrieb_alt.Value
        Unload Me
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you execute this:

```
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & Chr(10) & neu
```

The `Bold` setting for the cell becomes uniform -- it erases any knowledge of substring formatting.

So the solution is to parse the complete value in a loop, and identify all the dates and make them bold.

At the same time I would suggest some way to reduce the duplication of code and merge all different cases (first bullet, not first bullet, modification only) into one generic way:

```
Private Sub Fertig_Click()
    Dim neu As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'No Changes
    If mitschrieb_neu.Value = "" And mitschrieb_alt.Value = ActiveCell.Value Then
        Unload Me
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Join the old value with the new value and put a linefeed 
    ' in between only if both are not empty.
    ' Also insert the date before the new value, if it is not empty
    ActiveCell.Value = mitschrieb_alt.Value _
        & IIf(mitschrieb_alt.Value <> "" And mitschrieb_neu.Value <> "", Chr(10), "") _
        & IIf(mitschrieb_neu.Value <> "", Date & ": " & mitschrieb_neu.Value, "")

    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = False ' start with removing all bold
    ' Search for all colons and put prededing date in bold (if it is a date)
    i = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ": ")
    Do While i
        ' Make sure to only put in bold when it is a date, otherwise skip this ":"
        If i > 10 And IsDate(Mid(ActiveCell.Value, i - 10, 10)) Then
            ActiveCell.Characters(i - 10, 10).Font.Bold = True
        End If
        ' find next
        i = InStr(i + 1, ActiveCell.Value, ": ")
    Loop

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much.